# How can I key and value to same object on repeated clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, click

I apologise if this question is basic or not asked properly. I have been searching the site for hours to try and get a fix...

I am trying to make a guessing game.
On grabbing the dropdown  value on submit, I check the grabbed value against the key from another array object (theComputer[i]). If there is a matching property, and its value is true, add the key and value to compTempObj{}. Then on repeated dropdown submits, repeat the above process, each time adding the matching property & value to the same compTempObj{}. It does almost work except, it adds a new object for each click, rather than to the same Object.

The dropdown:

```
<select class="featureList">
<option class="charFeature">male</option>
<option class="charFeature">female</option>
<option class="charFeature">black hair</option>
<option class="charFeature">white hair</option>
<option class="charFeature">blonde hair</option>
<option class="charFeature">red hair</option>
<option class="charFeature">blue hair</option>
<option class="charFeature">purple hair</option>
<option class="charFeature">beard</option>
<option class="charFeature">moustache</option>
<option class="charFeature">glasses</option>
<option class="charFeature">earrings</option>
<option class="charFeature">hat</option>
<option class="charFeature">green eyes</option>
<option class="charFeature">black eyes</option>
</select>
```

My JS:

```
//Get SELECT values
function grabInputVal() {
    // click event on <select> submit
    $(".pickAFeatureBtn").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Assign <select> value to var
        var computerHas = ($(".featureList").val());
        theComputer;
        //check theComputer array for computerHas(select) property
        for (var i = 0; i < theComputer.length; i++) {
            // line below check for property val from dropdown against theComputer 
            if (theComputer[i].hasOwnProperty(computerHas) && theComputer[i][computerHas] === true) {
                var compTempObj = {};
                // compTempObj.prop = computerHas;
                compTempObj[computerHas] = theComputer[i][computerHas];
                compTempArr.push(compTempObj);
                console.log(compTempArr);
            } else {
                // Run function to make computer guess will go here
                console.log('Noooooooooo!');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the scope of `compTempObj` is local to the click event handler.  On every click it gets created because its definition is in the click function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < theComputer.length; i++) {
    // line below check for property val from dropdown against theComputer 
    if (theComputer[i].hasOwnProperty(computerHas) && theComputer[i][computerHas] === true) {


        // THIS VARIABLE IS LOCAL SCOPE!!  
        // Move the definition up higher to have a larger scope
        var compTempObj = {};


        // compTempObj.prop = computerHas;
        compTempObj[computerHas] = theComputer[i][computerHas];
        compTempArr.push(compTempObj);
        console.log(compTempArr);
     } else {
        // Run function to make computer guess will go here
        console.log('Noooooooooo!');
     }
}
```

I'm confused about `compTempArr`.  It doesn't have a definition so I don't know the scope of that variable.

If you want to reuse `compTempObj`, put its scope up higher, or make it a global variable.

## EDIT

If `compTempArr` is global, you can do the following and reuse `compTempObj`

```
for (var i = 0; i < theComputer.length; i++) {
    // line below check for property val from dropdown against theComputer 
    if (theComputer[i].hasOwnProperty(computerHas) && theComputer[i][computerHas] === true) {


        // THIS VARIABLE IS LOCAL SCOPE!!  
        // Move the definition up higher to have a larger scope
        var compTempObj = compTempArr[0] || {};


        // compTempObj.prop = computerHas;
        compTempObj[computerHas] = theComputer[i][computerHas];

        if(compTempArr.length === 0)
            compTempArr.push(compTempObj);
        console.log(compTempArr);
     } else {
        // Run function to make computer guess will go here
        console.log('Noooooooooo!');
     }
}
```

What I'm doing is pushing the `compTempObj` onto the `compTempArr` as the first property.  IDK if you're using `compTempArr` for anything else, but since it is globally scoped, you *can* do that.  HOWEVER!! I recommend doing the following:

- Rename your variables so that they explain what you're trying to do or what they describe.  `temp` is a TERRIBLE naming practice, don't do it!
- Define your game data as a single object and have that object be globally scoped.  That way your game logic can access the game data and not worry about scoping.
- Define your functions as named functions and pass them into the event handlers.  That way you can organize your game logic in one place, and not have your game logic and your game setup all mixed together.

Good luck!

Comment: compTempArr is an array defined globally. Thank you, I will try putting compTempObj next to it in the code.

Comment: In that case, I'll edit my answer for another solution

Comment: You have saved the other half of my hair from being pulled out. I've spent all day experiencing imposter syndrome because of this. Thanks again.

Comment: Ha! Glad I could help!  Definitely try and separate your code into chunks.  It may not sound like much, but if the code looks more organized, it's MUCH easier to debug!

Answer (score 0):

in each options you probably need to add value attribute to it.

```
<select class="featureList">
  <option class="charFeature" value="male" >male</option>
  <option class="charFeature" value="female" >female</option>
  <option class="charFeature" value="black hair" >black hair</option>
  ....
</select>
```

then var computerHas = ($(".featureList").val()); you will get the value of your option :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm totally missing something I think the answer is to simply move the variable declaration outside of the function. You're re-creating the object every time the click event executes. So instead of...

```
$(".pickAFeatureBtn").on('click', function(e) {
    ...
    var compTempObj = {};
    ...
}
```

...do...

```
var compTempObj = {};
$(".pickAFeatureBtn").on('click', function(e) {
    ...
}
```

Depending on the scope of the grabInputVal function you may need to put it outside of that though.

Also, as Plaimanus Lueondee pointed out, you're option tags need a value attribute. Or just use the text of the selected option like so...

```
$(".featureList option:selected").text();
```

Comment: And just for clarification - how are you using the grabInputVal function? When/how is that called? Because it seems unnecessary (though I can't know for sure unless I were able to see all of your code).

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. I'm just a student and I'm trying to push myself a bit with this project so appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you to get into right direction-

1. `var computerHas = ($(".featureList").val());` gives you an array so what value are you referring? (Check if you wanna use `$(".featureList").each(function(){})`)
2. `var compTempObj` is overwritten each time you call the function. Hence is it new everytime.

Possibly you should use-

```
var YourVariable;
// Since it is defined outside the function value will not be overwritten each time function is called

    function your_function(){
        ............YOUR CODE ..........

        // YourVariable = AssignNewValue

        ............MORE CODE ..........
    }
```

Comment: select value is not array unless it is a `<select multiple>`

Comment: `$(".featureList").val()` will give you only first value not all the value. And to refer sepcific value we can use `$(".featureList").eq(INDEX).val()`.